# Force refresh UI to change button colour and content quicker

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I have the following code that gets data from CloudKit, checks if the property "Completed" is false and adds one to the taskCount if so.

After it has iterated through the tasks it update the content and colour of a button.

The issue is that after the code is all executed it takes several seconds for the view to actually update and the number on the button as well as the colour to change.

Is there a way I can force a refresh or something after I update the button colour and content?

```
let taskManager = CloudKitTaskManager(database: CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase)
    taskManager.getSummaryOfTasks {
        tasks in
        for index in 0...tasks.count-1 {
            if ("False" == tasks[index].completed){
                self.taskCount = self.taskCount + 1
            }
        }
        self.dueButton.setTitle(String(self.taskCount) + "\nOutstanding", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        if (self.taskCount == 0) {
            self.dueButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:52/255, green:152/255, blue:219/255, alpha:1.0)
            self.dueButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }else if(self.taskCount > 0 && self.taskCount <= 5){
            self.dueButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:243/255, green:156/255, blue:18/255, alpha:1.0)
            self.dueButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }else if(self.taskCount > 5){
            self.dueButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:231/255, green:76/255, blue:60/255, alpha:1.0)
            self.dueButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }

    }
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The update of the user interface must happen on the main thread. You should use GCD to dispatch the UI update code to the appropriate queue.

Comment: @iOSX Could you expand, I'm fairly new to swift and some googleing doesn't really help with force reloading the UI on the GCD

Comment: Please see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32533786/3617012

Comment: Your algorithm is very inefficient. How many task are you looping through? It could theoretically take hours main queue or not to loop through a large enough dataset.

Comment: @Mika This is the only way I know to loop through the data, I couldn't find a way to query CloudKit for only records that Complete as False, If you know how or can suggest a better way to loop through your input would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completion handler for the CloudKit method is not guaranteed to run on the main queue, so you must dispatch the user interface related code to it like that:

```
let taskManager = CloudKitTaskManager(database: CKContainer.defaultContainer().privateCloudDatabase)
    taskManager.getSummaryOfTasks {
        tasks in
        for index in 0...tasks.count-1 {
            if ("False" == tasks[index].completed){
                self.taskCount = self.taskCount + 1
            }
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.dueButton.setTitle(String(self.taskCount) + "\nOutstanding", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            if (self.taskCount == 0) {
                self.dueButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:52/255, green:152/255, blue:219/255, alpha:1.0)
                self.dueButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }else if(self.taskCount > 0 && self.taskCount <= 5){
                self.dueButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:243/255, green:156/255, blue:18/255, alpha:1.0)
                self.dueButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }else if(self.taskCount > 5){
                self.dueButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:231/255, green:76/255, blue:60/255, alpha:1.0)
                self.dueButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks :) The way I tried with dispatch_async didn't work, had a completion handler, maybe old code or something.